# Can I remap Caps to Alt-Tab?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to remap CapsLock to the more useful Alt-Tab.

Is that possible?

(I'm using KDE Plasma if that matters)

Comment: Do you want to remap CapsLock, or do you want CapsLock to cycle to the next window? (The first implies the second, but you could do the second one directly as well.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I actually want to cycle to the next window only in KDE, but if I set CycleWindow it to CapsLock, then Caps still gets toggled. So I also need to disable that somehow.